# Trying to make a buy transaction on-chain on the solana network, but get seller_trade_state. Error Code: ContraintRaw

Tags: javascript, anchor, web3js, solana-web3js

I'm trying to execute a buy_now transaction using the Magic Eden API, but when I execute the transaction.

I receive an AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. Error Code: ConstraintRaw. Error Number: 2003. Error Message: A raw constraint was violated. and I don't know how to fix it, here's my code:

```
async function buyToken(user, params){
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(
            'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/instructions/buy_now', {
            params,
            headers
        });
        

        let txSigned = res.data.txSigned;
        const txn = await web3.Transaction.from(Buffer.from(txSigned.data));

        let buySignature = provider.wallet.signTransaction(txn);

        const latestBlockHash = await conn.getLatestBlockhash();
        
        let stategy = {
            blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
            signature: buySignature,
          }
        
        web3.sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(conn, txn.serialize(), stategy);    
    }catch(e){
        console.error('buyToken', e);
    }

}
```

here's the params I send to Magic Eden api to receive the instructions:

```
{
  buyer: 'DizqnaiTLTkTqXG759whvyVisCfuUUcA4VeQnJKQLaaN',
  seller: 'GtXNVaeeRQ95SdE6rjePHJLpaRe94FrN7KQNUmNj7jke',
  auctionHouseAddress: 'E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe',
  tokenMint: '8PHtyRngia1EQT99BA6ysbpdUjwXExRKkH3VUT3JeWcA',
  tokenATA: '6tfMBkUAYzcKcHkKBDAF8xrAoqXoAzsyB2WyB5XRmkcr',
  price: 0.019,
  sellerReferral: 'autMW8SgBkVYeBgqYiTuJZnkvDZMVU2MHJh9Jh7CSQ2'
}
```

Here the result after sending the transaction:

```
logs: [
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Deposit',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K success',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Buy',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: {"price":19000000,"buyer_expiry":0}',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K consumed 27892 of 590535 compute units',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K success',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: ExecuteSale',
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: seller_trade_state. Error Code: ConstraintRaw. Error Number: 2003. Error Message: A raw constraint was violated.',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K consumed 23877 of 562643 compute units',
    'Program M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K failed: custom program error: 0x7d3'
  ]
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No not yet, still trying to figure that out

Comment: Hi @MichaelFoisy What is tokenATA? Is it token account? I always get 401 status code when I request this api.

Comment: Yes, thats because you need an API key from MagicEden

Comment: Stuck with same issue. Did you finally figured out how to solve?